# g3d.utils not (anymore) available?

Tags: java, libgdx

Last week i tried to start coding with the libgdx library.
As i would like to try it's 3d context i rode the tutorial of Xoppa: http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/

Well, i understood his examples and started to code in eclipse.
But as soon as i got to the modelbuilder usage i stuck:

```
@Override
public void create() {      
    ...

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    ...
}
```

i imported a few other classes without problems, but i didn't find ...g3d.utils.modelbuilder

I googled and took a look at their github, where the package g3d.utils. exists.
And now, i don't know anymore. i'm using the latest stable build 0.9.8

I hope you can help me. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new 3D API (which is what Xoppa has been working on) is only available in post-0.9.8 builds, which at the moment is the "nightly" builds: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html